# Heating of Water, Reversible/irrevserible process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy, reversibility

I'm hoping that someone can help me understand this problem. I am determining which of these processes are reversible and irreversible. If we had some beaker of water at room temperature which came in contact with a hot plate (raising the water's temperature to boiling point) would this be a reversible or irreversible process? The second case, is that the water's temperature was increased by coming in contact with a plate that infinitesimally increased its temperature until the water was at boiling point. My current take on the problem is that the first case is an irreversible process (violent changes increase entropy and thus creates new entropy), and for the second case, I believe the process is reversible (slow changes leave total entropy of the universe unchanged). Do these answers and my reasoning align with the definitions of reversible and irreversible processes?

Comment: Why would you think not?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: "infinitesimally increased"  means  "infinitely slow increased" ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @AlekseyDruggist